# Show that a set $ F $ is uncountable

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $$ \{a,b,c\}^n = \big\{(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n): x_j \in \{a,b,c\} \big\}$$ and

$$ \{a,b,c\}^{*} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{a,b,c\}^n.$$

Consider the set $ F = \big\{ f: \{a,b,c\}^{*} \to \{a,b,c\} \big\}$ and show that $ F $ is not countable.

I've tried a couple of solutions:

i) No bijection between $ F \to \mathbb{N} $. Although I've tried to use Cantors diagonalizing argument I'm getting nowhere, since the arguments of $ f$ is such a mess.

ii) $ F $ is clearly an infinite set. Then it's sufficient to show that $ \mid F \mid \neq \mathbb{N}^0$ (aleph-null) or $ \mid F \mid > \mathbb{N}^0 $.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Do you know how to prove $2^{\aleph_0}$ (or alternatively, the set of all infinite binary sequences) is uncountable? You may use the same argument, by using that the set $\{a,b,c\}^*$ is countable.

Comment: I am not familiar with it. Do you mean this? https://www.math.brown.edu/reschwar/MFS/handout8.pdf (page 4) I'll dig into it

Comment: @HanulJeon Alright, I'm now familiar with the set of all infinite binary sequences. What kind of argument should one apply, similar to n'th digit is opposite to f^-1(n)?

Comment: Your one is a possible approach and probably the easiest.

Comment: The bijection part?

Comment: I am not sure what the bijection part means. However, if you know the well-known diagonalization argument, then simply follow it with a small modification.

Answer (score 2):

The set $A=\{a,b,c\}^{*}$ is countable. Thus $P(A)$, the power set of $A$, is uncountable. Now we see $P(A)\cong\big\lbrace f:A\to \lbrace 0,1\rbrace\big\rbrace\subset F$, so $F$, too, is uncountable.

Comment: Is it always true that $ P(A) = \big\{f: A \to \{0,1 \} \big\} $ if A is countable?

Comment: @Oskar For each $B\subset A$, you can find a map $f\colon A\to\{0,1\}$ sending $a\in B$ to $1$ and $a\notin B$ to $0$. Conversely, for a map $f$, let $B=\{a\in A:f(a)=1\}$. This bijection exists for any set $A$, regardless of countability.

Comment: As @KentaS said, this caracterization always olds for any set. In particular you can prove with this caracterization that the cardinality of P(A) is always strictly bigger than the one of A.

Comment: @Oskar See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943927/how-can-i-form-a-bijection-between-mathcal-pa-and-2a?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

This proof is basically the hint that @Hanul_Jeon gave in the comments as well as a follow on to your attempt number $1$. First, note that the set $\{a,b,c\}^{*}$ is countable. This is because there exists an injective function between this set and a subset of the rational numbers. One such function can be formally written as

$$g(\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\})=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{h(x_i)}{4^i}$$

where

$$h(x_i)=\begin{cases} 
      1 & x_i=a\\
      2 & x_i=b \\
      3 & x_i=c
   \end{cases}$$

Now that we have shown that $\{a,b,c\}^{*}$ is countable, we can show that $F$ is uncountable. Let $r:\{a,b,c\}^{*}\to\mathbb{N}$ be a bijection between $\{a,b,c\}^{*}$ and the natural numbers and suppose by way of contradiction that $F$ is countable. Then we can list the elements of $F$ in a bijection with $\mathbb{N}$:

$$f_1:\{a,b,c\}^{*}\to\{a,b,c\}$$

$$f_2:\{a,b,c\}^{*}\to\{a,b,c\}$$

$$f_3:\{a,b,c\}^{*}\to\{a,b,c\}$$

$$\vdots$$

We will now construct a new function $f^{*}$ that is not on this list (Technically, the diagonal arguement is a constructive arguement, not contradiction. But its easier to understand as a proof by contradiction so I'll leave that terminology from above). For each element in $\{a,b,c\}^{*}$, define

$$f^{*}(\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\})=K[f_{r(\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\})}(\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\})]$$

where

$$K(x)=\begin{cases} 
      a & x=b\\
      b & x=c \\
      c & x=a
   \end{cases}$$

There is a lot to unpack in that function, but the basic idea is this: To find what $f^{*}$ does to an arbitrary element $s\in\{a,b,c\}^{*}$ do the following

- Use the bijection $r$ to get the natural number corresponding to the $s$
- Go to the function $f_{r(s)}$ in the list (the one we assumed to exist)
- Change the output of $f^{*}$ to be different from $f_{r(s)}$

In this way, we are assured that $f^{*}$ is different from all functions on the list. As this is a contradiction, we conclude that $F$ is not countable.